# Delete artifacts after searching old artifacts in Artifactory

Tags: bash, curl, artifactory

I need to write a shell script, that can get outdated artifacts from JFROG by using REST API and delete them.

I get a list of artifacts by command

```
curl -u user:password "http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/api/search/dates?dateFields=created&from=1467052559000&to=1497588559000&repos=current-repo"
```

and get an output like

```
"results" : [ {
    "uri" : "http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/api/storage/current-repo/first artifact/artfoulder folder/file.tzs",
    "created" : "2017-04-10T11:33:50.190+03:00"
  }, {
    "uri" : "http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/api/storage/current-repo/second artifact/artfoulder folder/file2.tzs",
    "created" : "2017-04-10T11:33:50.140+03:00"
  } ]
```

and other artifacts

After I successfully got the list of these artifacts, I need to delete them.

My questions:

1. Is there a simple way to do it? Or I need to parse output strings with shell, put links in array and delete by REST API command one by one?
2. It there a way to get only first-level artifact folders, that are outdated and delete them (**first artifact** and **second artifact** in my case)

Answer (score 2):

Why not using a script is already ready specifically for that:
https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-scripts/blob/master/cleanup/aqlCleanup.groovy

All you will need to do is change the AQL query to search artifacts on specific date range and that is it. This will automatically clean up.

Comment: Could you tell me, how to use groovy script in Jenkins? It should be a Jenkins job in my case.

Comment: In Jenkins you can run a command line job inside the Generic build, and just run the groovy script. You will need to have groovy installed on the Jenkins machine. To run a groovy job just run the following: "groovy fileNeme.groovy"

PLEASE NOTE, the groovy file I've referred is set with specific AQL condition. Please make sure to alter this condition to your own needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will pay attention to it, of course. Could you tell me, how can I make it find only first-level directories (the information is above)? And is it possible to do it just with a curl command?